# how local variables work inside nest function in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, local-variables, nested-function

I have the code:

```
def main(m):
    res = m
    def help(a, b):
        print(res)
        #res = min(res, a*b)
    help(3,2)
    return res
main(3)
```

The code works. However

```
def main(m):
    res = m
    def help(a, b):
        print(res)
        res = min(res, a*b)
    help(3,2)
    return res
main(3)
```

it raise `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'res' referenced before assignment`

```
def main(m):
    global res
    res = m
    def help(a, b):
        print(res)
        res = min(res, a*b)
    help(3,2)
    return res
main(3)
```

It seems that I add `global  res` does not change. what happens here? How to update `res` inside the function `help`?

Comment: The issue is that adding the line `res = min(res, a*b)` actually introduces a new variable `res` within the `help` function which is *different* from the variable `res` within `main`. I'll write up a full answer in a sec.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short description of the scoping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the inner function that the `res` variable is nonlocal, like this:

```py
def main(m):
    res = m
    def help(a, b):
        nonlocal res
        print(res)
        res = min(res, a*b)
    help(3,2)
    return res
main(3)
```

You can read from a non locally scoped variable without issue in a function, but if you try to write to a variable then python assumes that you want to create a new locally scoped variable. That local variable hides and prevents access to any similarly named variable that may exist in the namespace of higher scopes, like outer functions or global variables.  To inform it that you do not want to create a local variable and want to access the outer scope variable you need to use the `nonlocal` keyword as in the above example.

Using `global res` does not fix it because global variables are at the top level of the namespace hierarchy and the `res` variable that you are trying to access is not. The `res` you want to access is in between the global scope and the local scope. That is why you need to use `nonlocal` instead of `global`. If `res` were at the top/external level then `global` would have been the solution.

Comment: cool, any idea why I add `global res` does not work?

Comment: @jason Because global variables are at the top level of the namespace hierarchy and the res you are trying to access is not. The res you are accessing is in between the global scope and the local scope. That is why you need to use nonlocal instead of global. I have edited my answer to include this explanation which I left out in the first  place.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are introducing a new, uninitialized local variable in the `help()` function, then trying to pass it to the `min(res, a*b)` function.

Instead of trying to deal with the scoping issues, you could just return `min(res, a*b)` and assign it to `res` outside of the `help()` function:

```
def main(m):
    res = m
    def help(a, b):
        # print(res)
        return min(res, a*b)
    res = help(3,2)
    return res
```

Answer (score 1):

The relevant code here is

```py
res = m
def help(a, b):
    print(res)
    res = min(res, a*b)  # may or may not be commented out
```

This is not doing what you think it is.

Let's go through this line-by-line:

1. `res = m`: this defines the variable `res`, with value `m`, which lives in the `main` function
2. `def help(a, b)`: begins a function definition. Within the `help` function, you are able to define entirely new variables which are insulated from the variables in `main`
3. `print(res)`: this prints the value of variable `res`. To find the value of `res`, Python will first look in `help` function a variable named `res`. If there is none, it will search the `main` function (i.e. the parent scope) for a variable named `res`. (If there were to be none *there*, it would continue to search higher and higher scopes.) As it turns out, in your example, whether or not there is a variable named `res` in the `help` function depends on whether or not line 4 is commented out!
4. `res = min(res, a*b)`: This does not do what you think it does. What you *want* it to do is to change the variable value of the `res` variable in the `main` function. However, Python will instead create a *new* variable `res` within the `help` function and set its value to `min(res, a*b)`.

This is why you are getting an `UnboundLocalError`. Because when line 4 is uncommented, then `print(res)` refers to the variable named `res` in the `help` function, not the `main` function. But when line 4 is commented out, there is no `res` variable in the `help` function, so `print(res)` instead uses the variable in the `main` function.

So, how to fix it? Actually pretty simple, just change the code to:

```py
def help(a, b):
    nonlocal res
    print(res)
    res = min(res, a*b)
```

The `nonlocal` statement tells Python, "hey, the `res` variable is coming from an outer scope".

Comment: excellent explains. May I add `global res` before the `help()` function to turn `res` a global variable?

Comment: Yes, that would work. However, by the looks of your code, it would be more appropriate to have no `global` statement anywhere and a single `nonlocal res` statement within the `help` function. (Since you `return res` from `main`, should `res` really be a global variable?)

Comment: I try add `global res` outside the `help()`, it still raise the error.

Comment: I misread your question. Adding `global res` *outside* `help` will not work, because then you're referring to the `res` in the `main` function. I've offered a solution in my anwer, did you try that?